# How to count total views using Middleware and ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

Assuming I have `aaaa.com/Class`, if a user navigates to this link, I want `PageCount` in my database to increment by 1. Please Help me.

Comment: Hi @destinyidika,any update about this case?

Comment: Thanks bro for your swift response, I have tried the Above Implementation, it seems to just work out if only i can figure out how to solve the Error it is getting. The Error is {Cannot resolve scoped service 'MVC_Visited_Count.ApplicationDBContext' from root provider.'}. Any help on solving this will greatly be Appreciated. Thanks once more bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url in middleware by:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;

public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        //get the url
        var url = httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
        if(url== "your link url")
        {
            //find your data
            var p = _context.Page.Find(1);
            p.PageCount++;
            _context.Update(p);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```